# Error en Big query: Project name needs to be separated by dot from dataset name, not by colon in table name

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, gcp

Estoy trabajando en la creación de un código SQL que elimine y vuelva a crear la tabla con los datos actualizados cargados desde un CSV en cloud storage. Sin embargo, me aparece el siguiente error y no sé cómo resolverlo.

SQL:

```
DELETE FROM `data-centric-dev.mydataset_br.prueba_1`

CREATE TABLE `data-centric-dev.mydataset_br.prueba_1`
AS
SELECT *
FROM `gs://mybucket-br/Materiales.csv`
```

Error:

Project name needs to be separated by dot from dataset name, not by colon in table name "gs://mybucket-br/Materiales.csv".

Answer (score 0):

Se debe crear una tabla externa desde una URI:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE EXTERNAL TABLE mydataset.sales

    OPTIONS (
      format = 'CSV',
      uris = ['gs://mybucket/sales.csv']
    )
```

Según esta documentación: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-cloud-storage?hl=es-419#ddl